# Integrate by every number of elements returns unequal vector lengths

Tags: r

I have a vector and I want to integrate on it by every specific number of elements `(s parameter)`.

```
library(Bolstad2)

myfunc <- function(s, v)
{
    sapply(seq(1, length(v), by = s),
           function(i)  Bolstad2::sintegral(
               1:length(v), v[i])
               )$int 
}

v <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
s <- 2
p <- myfunc(s, v)
```

Right now I am receiving: `unequal vector lengths`.

I am not sure how to integrate by every `s` elements.

(It's not necessary to use the `Bolstad2` package, I prefer though the simpson's method)

Comment: You might want to have a look at [rollapply()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-6/topics/rollapply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about what you exactly want to achieve, but you need to keep the same length of two arguments within `sintegral()`.

Do you mean something like below?

```
myfunc <- function(s, v)
{
  r <- sapply(seq(1, length(v), by = s),
         function(i)  sintegral(
           1:length(v), rep(v[i],length(v))), simplify = F
  )
  sapply(r, "[[",3)
}
```

then you will get

```
> p
[1]  9 27 45 63 81
```

Comment: I must get 5 different values for the integral . I want to integrate by every 2 elements.

Comment: Yes, I think that is ok!Integrate by every 2 elements. I don't understans the `3` parameter in the last sapply method though.

Comment: @George, since `r` is a list of three members, `$int` as the third entry to access. You can view the structure of `r` to see how it looks like